# ProtoBuf conversion Method To/From not working with interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

In my configuration serialized by ProtoBuf, I've an interface, `IPoint` that is put on every model of my configuration that can be referenced by another model of my configuration.
Every node of my configuration implements `IConfigurationNode`, which is the root parent of every model I've.

I've a `Surrogate` for this, since in most of the case, the IPoint is put on a specific node of my hiearchy, and since Proto doesn't support multiple inheritance, I did the following:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ConfigurationNodeSurrogate<T>
    where T : class, IConfigurationNode
{
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
    public IConfigurationNode ConfigurationNode { get; set; }

    [ProtoConverter]
    public static T From(ConfigurationNodeSurrogate<T> configurationNodeSurrogate)
    {
        return configurationNodeSurrogate?.ConfigurationNode as T;
    }

    [ProtoConverter]
    public static ConfigurationNodeSurrogate<T> To(T configurationNode)
    {
        return configurationNode == null ? null : new ConfigurationNodeSurrogate<T> {ConfigurationNode = configurationNode};
    }
}
```

And I declare it like this:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(IPoint), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(ConfigurationNodeSurrogate<IPoint>));
```

So like this it should serialize it as a `IConfigurationNode`.

`IConfiguration` and all the classes below have the `ProtoContract` attribute, and they are all registering all their possible childs.

When I try to serialize the whole thing, no issues, but when I try deserializing, I've an exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'ConfigurationNodeSurrogate`1[IPoint]' to type 'IConfigurationNode'.
   at proto_518(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.ReadNetObject(Object value, ProtoReader source, Int32 key, Type type, NetObjectOptions options)
   at proto_235(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_3(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_506(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.ReadNetObject(Object value, ProtoReader source, Int32 key, Type type, NetObjectOptions options)
   at proto_327(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_3(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_506(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.ReadNetObject(Object value, ProtoReader source, Int32 key, Type type, NetObjectOptions options)
   at proto_183(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_175(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_173(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_3(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_506(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.ReadNetObject(Object value, ProtoReader source, Int32 key, Type type, NetObjectOptions options)
   at proto_233(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_3(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_506(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.ReadNetObject(Object value, ProtoReader source, Int32 key, Type type, NetObjectOptions options)
   at proto_271(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_3(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader)
   at proto_506(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoReader reader, Type type, Object value, Boolean noAutoCreate)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type, SerializationContext context)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize[T](Stream source)
```

I've a feeling it is related to the fact that some of the "IPoint" DataMember I've are actually null, I'm not sure how the converters handle this. Is my Surrogate correctly implemented?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention, but my `IPoint` directly inherits from the `IConfigurationNode`

**EDIT 2**
Here is an example that illustrate my case

```
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault =true)]
public interface IConfigurationNode {
    List<IConfigurationNode> Childs{get;set;}
}

[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault =true)]
public interface IPoint: IConfigurationNode{

}

[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault=true)]
public class SomeClass:IConfigurationNode
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    List<IConfigurationNode> Childs{get;set;}

    public SomeClass(){
        Childs= new List<IConfigurationNode>(); 
    }
}

[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault=true)]
public SomeNodeA:SomeClass, IPoint
{
}

[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault=true)]
public SomeNodeB: SomeClass{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public IPoint SomeReference{get;set;}
}



//Some test code:

SomeClass configuration = new SomeClass();
SomeNodeA nodeA = new SomeNodeA();
SomeNodeB nodeB = new SomeNodeB();
nodeB.SomeReference = nodeB;
configuration.Childs.Add(nodeA);
configuration.Childs.Add(nodeB);

byte[] bytes = ProtoBufHelper.ProtoSerialize(configuration);
SomeClass  configuration2 = ProtoBufHelper.ProtoDeserialize<SomeClass >(bytes);
```

**EDIT3** I currently imported the code of ProtoBuf in my solution to debug a little bit and trying to understand what is happening.

The weird thing is that it seems that when I'm trying to deserialize the property `ConfigurationNode` of the `ConfigurationNodeSurrogate`, in the class [BclHelper](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/src/protobuf-net/BclHelpers.cs#L561), it tries to get an element in the `NetCache`, which is the surrogate(and not the `IConfigurationNode as expected.) Not really sure why. I tried to reproduce it with a smaller example, and it did work. I've the feeling that the order changes something(meaning if the same class is serialized before but through an interface or not it's not serialized the same way).

Comment: If you could provide us a complete working sample showing the issue, it will help us to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mjwills I added some code to illustrate

Comment: @mjwills Doesn't seems to help a lot ;)